# Where can I get the xdg menu hierarchy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, menu, hierarchy, freedesktop.org

I've consulted the following articles and many more, but still don't understand one question --

What menu hierarchy do freedesktop (or Ubuntu or any modern distro) use?
Where can I get a list of such menu hierarchy? E.g., the "Accessories", "Internet", "Editor", "System" etc that type of things, and what corresponding Categories it is accepting from the .desktop file.

- https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/
- https://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html
- [How can I put my GTK application in the desktop menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815190/how-can-i-put-my-gtk-application-in-the-desktop-menus)
- [Desktop files: putting your application in the desktop menus](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)
- [ANATOMY OF A .DESKTOP FILE](https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/)

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

Under `/etc/xdg/menus/` (under Debian/Ubuntu).
E.g., `/etc/xdg/menus/gnome-applications.menu`.